# VIM: Duplicating the text of each line

Tags: vim

File Contains:

```
 aa
 bb
 cc
 dd
```

I need:

```
 aa aa
 bb bb
 cc cc
 dd dd
```

How can I do this??

Comment: Your best bet is to FORGET about "vim" and simply use "paste" from the command line or a shell script.  IMHO...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a regex:

```
%s/.*/& &/
```

Comment: You don't have to group nor you need the begin of line `^` you can just `:%s/.*/& &`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps there's a more clever way, but I would just enter visual block selection mode: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, go to the last line: <kbd>G</kbd>, select all the way to the right: <kbd>$</kbd>, and yank: <kbd>y</kbd>.

Then you'll end up back at the first line. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to begin inserting at the end of the first line. Enter a space, leave insert mode and press <kbd>p</kbd> to paste in what you previously yanked.

Comment: It won't work if the length of text in each line is different.

Comment: `set virtualedit=all` and you can paste the block where ever you want without working about inserting extra white-space.

Comment: Wow! Interesting tip, @PeterRincker. Still need to decide if I like all this extra freedom :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a unix environment:

```
:'<,'>! awk '{print $0, $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rectangular select the region to copy , yank it, then move point to the point where you want the text, then paste.

```
gg0
$<C-v>G<S-i>  

<esc> gg0 
<C-v> eeGygg$p
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with ex commands!

```
:g/./y|pu|-j
```

Long form:

```
:g/./yank|put|-1join
```

This similar to doing `yypkJ` for every line (which you can do like `:%norm yypkJ` if you want).

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :y
:h :pu
:h :j
:h range
:h :norm
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the beginning of the line. Do `yy` in command mode, go to end of line do `J`. `yy` copies the current line to buffer, `J` joins the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a macro. Go to the top of the file, start recording with `qq`, then do whatever to duplicate the first line. Maybe `YpkJ`, or really anything that works to turn "aa" into "aa aa". Then stop recording with `q` again.

To apply to the rest of the buffer, use `:2,$norm @q`, or use visual mode to select all the lines until the end, and type `:norm @q`.